# How to select following data in one single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using **postgres**

**Table 1: person**

```
Columns:: id,person_name,person_add,block_id
FK==>person(block_id) reference block(id)
```

**Table 2: block**

```
Columns:: id,block_name,district_id
FK==> block(district_id) reference district(id)
```

**Table 3: district**

```
Columns:: id,district_name,state_id
FK==> district(state_id) reference state(id)
```

**Table 4: state**

```
Columns:: id,state_name,country_id
FK==> state(country_id) reference country(id)
```

**Table 5: country**

```
Columns:: id,country_name
```

i have written query as follow::

When i want block wise details

```
SELECT p.id,p.person_name,b.block_name,d.district_name,s.state_name,c.country_name
FROM person p 
INNER JOIN block b ON b.id = p.block_id
INNER JOIN district d ON d.id = b.district_id
INNER JOIN state s ON s.id = d.state_id
INNER JOIN country c ON c.id = s.country_id
WHERE b.id = ? OR d.id = ? OR s.id = ? OR c.id = ?
```

how to write it in single query for following cases ???

1.i have only country id and s.id,d.id,b.id are going to be null(here above query gives fine result)

2.i have country id and state id and d.id,b.id(here it will prefer according to c.id)

3.i have country id, state id and district id b.id(same here it will prefer according to c.id)

4.i have country id,state id,district id and block id is null(same here it will prefer according to c.id)

Comment: Check for null values, i.e. similar to `where (b.id = :p1 or :p1 is null) and (d.id = :p2 or :p2 is null) ...`

Comment: Please post all your expected result.

Comment: I have edited it again and have mentioned cases properly and also mentioned that i am using POSTGRES

Comment: If the block is related to the district, the district to state and state to country, then that's the order of nulls you are gonna have (from country backwards). You won't be able to find a country while having null on the state, since the state is the step that get's you to the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the criteria is optional. You may be searching for a certain country, state, district and block or for instance only for a country.

So check each variable for null. Something like this:

```
SELECT p.id,p.person_name,b.block_name,d.district_name,s.state_name,c.country_name
FROM person p 
INNER JOIN block b    ON b.id = p.block_id
INNER JOIN district d ON d.id = b.district_id
INNER JOIN state s    ON s.id = d.state_id 
INNER JOIN country c  ON c.id = s.country_id
WHERE (b.id = :block_id    OR :block_id is null)
  AND (d.id = :district_id OR :district_id is null)
  AND (s.id = :state_id    OR :state_id is null)
  AND (c.id = :country_id  OR :country_id is null);
```

(You can also move the conditions to the `ON` clauses; whichever you prefer.)